# html iframes vs jquery.load() when adding content dynamically (no php, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a project where I need to dynamically build up web content coming from different sources (same domain). All the main libraries and css are managed centrally but depending on a configuration I have to add pages (html and embedded JavaScript) as 'tab content'.

My first approach was using iframes and it worked well besides the annoyance that I had some duplicte code (especially the header). I also had some issues with frame sizes but I could handle that in the end.

Now of course I read that iframes are evil but almost all the alternatives I found were using php or something else server-side. Unfortunately my web server does not provide anything like that, so I came across jQuery's load function. My first attempt is satisfying but what unsettles me now is managing (global) variables (and functions). Because jQuery.load() simply inserts the code into the DOM I always need to be extremely careful about naming here. For example I usually have a function called init() which is included in the body for the onload-Event. But every other page will need one of those as well.

The project is very likely to grow (maybe at some point even external developers will take part). I am now at a point where I have to decide which path to take and I am torn.

So my Question: Even though iframes are evil, im my experience it is a lot easier and secure than inserting the code via jQuery (in this particular case). Oh, that was not a question... The question would be: Is there any way to encapsulate variables and functions into the content that I load with jQuery? Or might there be a better way of handling variables/functions in this case anyways.

I am grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: actually when using load() your main window will always be the "main" window. when loading html pieces with load(), make sure just to load certain divs (without all the html and head and body tags) and use callbacks instead. for instance, on your external html files, dont use any js at all, rather put all js in one file on index.html and depending on what content you load, fire that specific callback. thats what worked for me! :) might not be the best way, though

Comment: Is that page public available and is it required that the content you load is visible to the search engine and associated with the page it is shown on?

Comment: No, the page will not be public. It will be service pages for a project on a plc which has this very simple web server. That is the reason why i do not have PHP or anything.

Comment: But you can preprocess the parts that should be loaded with e.g. php , grunt or something else and upload it to your webspace?

Comment: @t.niese: No, I would not know how. The Plc does not have PHP but it will provide the information about what content to use right after it boots. Just an xml telling, what to add where.

Comment: If anyone is still interested in this question: I am going to use a modular approach using require.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to suggest to do it this way, but because you want to to know how this can be done, here some code to illustrate how it could be done (only rudimentary tested and should not be used without further testing).

While I'm not sure if you could (and i think you should not) structure your project that way i hope that it will help to solve your problem.

The main code of your page:

```
var app = {};
(function() {
    var nextId = 1;
    var elementById = {};

     app.registerContent = function( id, initFunction ) {
        try {
            initFunction(elementById[id]);
        } catch( e ) {
            //if an error happend in the init script catch it so that the script will not break
            console.error(e);
        }
        //remove the jquery element from the list
        delete elementById[id];
     }


     //custom loader to handle init script
     jQuery.fn.customLoader = function(url) {
         var elm = $(this);
         var id = nextId++;
         //store the element where the data is loaded to in a list
         elementById[id] = elm;
         $.get(url,function(data) {
             //replace the id in the script so that the element the data is loaded into 
             // can be passed to the init script later.
             data = data.replace("%%unique-id%%",id);
             elm.html(data); //append the data to the element
         });
     }

     //a sample how you would load the content
     $(function() {
         $(".dest").customLoader("content.html");
     });

})();
```

The code in your requested data:

```
<div>some content</div>

<!-- the script that correspons to that part -->
<script>
//create a scope using a function that is executed directly
(function() {
    //using var to make the variables only visible to this place
    var uniqueId = %%unique-id%%; //this will be replaced by the loader to identify the element where the data is loaded to
    var someVar = 1;

    app.registerContent(uniqueId, initFunctionForTheContent)


    function initFunctionForTheContent(element) {
        element.css("background-color", "red")
    }

})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Even though I will not be going down that road now, I marked your answer as accepted, because it answeres the question very well.

Answer (score 2):

Not having a back end with a huge app and many developers sounds like hell. Sometimes things are best fitted on the server side e.g php's `include`.

Either way I would go with an MVC solution.

I have experience with backbone and underscore so I will give an example with that but there are many other MVC solutions.

If all you need to do is load some data you can use underscores templating which is very lightweight

You can do stuff like:

#### In the model:

```
 sum: function() {
      Sum certain properties of your objects. 
    }
```

#### In index.html

```
 <script type="text/template" id="sum-template">
      sum: <%    print(sum) %>
  </script
```

#### In the view

```
 sumTemplate: _.template($('#sum-template').html()),
 this.$el.find('#sum').html(this.sumTemplate({sum:Expenses.sum()}));
```

As you can see you can get data from different places and load them to certain HTML elements. It easy to manage on the long run.

In order to persist data you can free and paid hosted data bases a simple google search for

*redis hosting*, *mongodb hosting* etc... so you are not dependent on your current server.

Comment: I also found MVC-patterns overly-ugly and painful to maintain, but to each his own I guess.

Comment: I thought so too but after you get used to idea its great

Comment: @OneOfOne Well there are some many MVC patterns, some that are really strict and could be annoying and some that are less strict. Anyhow if you define a structure your self this is also a kind MVC pattern. If you have no structure then you will get problems if the project grows and you are not the only developer anymore :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look at some MVC's some time ago but forgot about them in the meantime. Good reason to dig into that subject again.

Comment: @t.niese I totally agree. First MVC for me was symfony and I found it too complicated but there are other frameworks which makes building much easier